# RethinkDB Filter lambda 2 fields

Tags: lambda, rethinkdb

I have a bit of a problem with a statement in RethinkDB.

I have the following set of data:

```
{
    candidate_details :{
        "name" : "User test 1"
    },
    for_job : "long-id-1234"
}
{
    candidate_details :{
        "name" : "User test 10"
    },
    for_job : "long-id-56789"
}
{
    candidate_details :{
        "name" : "User test 9"
    },
    for_job : "long-id-1234"
}
```

When i apply the following statement:

```
r.table("table").filter(lambda doc:
                                            doc.has_fields({"for_job_details":{"name"}}) &
                                            doc.has_fields({"candidate_details":{"name"}}) &
                                            (
                                                # candidate_query(doc) &
                                                # job_query(doc)
                                                doc['candidate_details']['name'].downcase().match('') &
                                                doc['for_job'].downcase().match('long-id-1234')

                                            ) &
                                            doc['company_id'].eq(company_id)
                                        ).run(rethink_conn)
```

It does not return anything.
I want it to return all "candidates" that have the id for job "long-id-1234" and match ""

What am i doing wrong?

If i eliminate any of the 2 statements (match), it works, but not together.
Also i want to do it in a single filter.
If i do 2 filters, it works.

**EDIT**

The problem is NOT caused by the `doc.has_fields` condition.

Comment: RethinkDB developer here. It might be a bug in RethinkDB's `match`. I'm going to investigate further.

Comment: @AtnNn i fixed my problem and i will post the solution here, but the "main" problem still exists.